# ImportError: cannot import name pygtkcompat

Tags: python, python-2.7, gstreamer, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I'm trying to run a program that tests pocketsphinx's ability to recognize audio in real time (code taken from [here](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/gstreamer/)), but I'm getting an ImportError every time it tries to import pygtkcompat from gi

```
from gi import pygtkcompat
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. The problem was because gi wasn't installed correctly and was in the wrong path. I removed and re-installed it a few times, but I must have been doing it wrong somehow because it took a few retries before it started working again.
The cause must have been using "sudo apt-get install python-gi" instead of pip (as sudo).